# What is meant by getIntent().getExtras()?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to Android development and I have come across something new while using Intent as getIntent().getExtras().

Can anyone please explain me how can we write getIntent().getExtras(),cause till now what I know is we can call method by creating object of that particular class but here we are call method getExtras() by using getIntent()method.

Comment: getIntent() is a Activity Class method returs Intent . getIntent().getExtras() returns the bundle which contains all extras .For more info Read [This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getIntent().getExtras() is used to get values from intent that are stored in bundle.
Intent class is used to switch between activities. But sometimes we need to send data from one activity to another. So, at this particular moment we need to set some values to intent that can be transferred to destination activity. We can achieve this by the following code -

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key1","someValue");
Intent intent=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putStringExtra("key","value");
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now, in the second activity we can get the value of "key" so we can use that in second activity. To do so, we use the getIntent().getIntent can store a Bundle. Let's see an example -

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
Bundle valueFromFirstActivity = intent.getExtras();
String valueOfKey = intent.getStringExtra("key");
String valueOfKey = bundle.getString("key1");
```

So this way, one can get values from activities. Bundle is a class that can hold values within itself and that instance of bundle can be given to intent using putExtras(). It is quite helpful in transferring the custom array list.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Kindly mark it correct . Hope It helps you.. :) Keep coding

Comment: Can you please suggest me links ,tutorials,website to improve or to learn Android development

Comment: sure, you can refer **Slidenerd** on youtube. For more, refer [link](http://androidhive.info) . Rest is on your research, Go through GitHub codes. Try to implement. Work on java.  That's all..It takes time..Keep Calm and Code

Answer (score 0):

> we can call method by creating object of that particular class

getIntent() is a method that returns an Intent object. When you call getIntent().getExtras(), first an Intent object is returned and then getExtras() method is invoked.

This way of calling is referred to as method chaining([Fluent Interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface))