# How to fix Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bundle

So I want to update the name of the account when the user is on the getting started activity.
I watched a YouTube tutorial and did what is on the video but I am having an error
`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

These are all the codes I used:

This is on the Getting Started Activity

```
        continueBtn = findViewById(R.id.continueBtn);
        continueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String Data = accountNameSignup.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(GettingStarted.this, HomeMenu.class);
                intent.putExtra("abc", Data);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

This is on the Profile account

```
        accountName = findViewById(R.id.accountName);
        Bundle bn = getIntent().getExtras();
        String updateName = bn.getString("abc");
        accountName.setText(String.valueOf(updateName));
```

The user will have to go through getting started activity first which he/she will enter personal details. After that it will redirect the user to the dashboard menu. The other menus are working fine but when I click the Profile menu, the app crashes and it gives me the error above.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Are `Profile account` and `HomeMenu` just different names for the same Activity?

Comment: @S-Sh no, they are different activitty. So I have three bottom nav menus, Explore, Home and Profile.

Comment: If you intend on retrieving a bundle extra, then you need to create a bundle and `putExtras` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47249949/2711811

Comment: @newbie then you should check that you actually include `"abc"` extra in intent when create Intent for **Profile** too

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions

1. ensure that the 'Data' being stored is actually from the variable 'Data' in your 'Getting Started Activity'. I would suggest you accustom to starting variable names with lowercases.
2. Use your logcat to display the actual stored data in the 'Getting Started' activity and then also the actual retrieved data in the 'Profile' activity to ensure the data is not null.
3. When fetching data from a bundle, set a default value.
4. Also, check your layout file to confirm that the refered views actually exist and are the view groups set in the class.

It might not be the exact solution to your problem but they are some debugging suggestions that might help you narrow down the bug and thus the solution